# Python Selenium javascript error: shape=rectangle is not supported

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using python selenium to automate the download of financial reports. To achieve this I have to insert my password using this virtual keyboard:

[image]

I'm trying to click every letter of my password through xpath:

```
object = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="alphaKeyboard"]/area[13]')
object.click()
```

The XPath to each letter is quite similar, only changes the number inside `*area[]*`

But I'm getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: shape=rectangle is not supported
```

I suppose this problem is related to the shape='rectangle' element that contains the virtual keyboard, the complete html element for each letter looks like this, for example for the letther 'F':

```
<area shape="rectangle" coords=" 72, 22, 93, 44" onclick="writeAlpha('F')" onmouseover="setHandCursor(document.alphaKeyboard)" onmouseout="setDefaultCursor(document.alphaKeyboard)">
```

Any suggestions with that?

I let you the URL if you want to try:

https://sucursalempresas.transaccionesbancolombia.com/SVE/control/BoleTransactional.bancolombia

Comment: just double checking, is the error thrown by the `object.click()` line?

Comment: Hi, @M Z, yeah the error is in the line object.click(). If you want to try this is the url: https://sucursalempresas.transaccionesbancolombia.com/SVE/control/BoleTransactional.bancolombia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a big shortcut for you on this one.

In your element, you have:

```
onclick="writeAlpha('F')"
```

On click that runs the javascript function `writeAlpha('F')`. You can run that function directly and not have to worry about the keyboard or xpaths at all.

Running it from the devtools console looks like this:

[image: Devtool Keypress]

In python you run javascript as such:

```
driver.execute_script("writeAlpha('F')")
```

You'll just need to  update the letter to send.

---

[Update] - Taking it a little further...

You can create your details as string, split it and send it with a loop like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://sucursalempresas.transaccionesbancolombia.com/SVE/control/BoleTransactional.bancolombia")

myKeys = "HELLOWORLD"
myKeys = myKeys.split()

for key in myKeys:
    driver.execute_script("writeAlpha('"+key+"')")
```

That outputs this:

[image: final keys to virtual keyobard]

Comment: Just beware... in general, you wouldn't want to use this method if your script was being used to test the site because this method shortcuts the UI.